# Django in Visual Studio: "ImportError cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'"

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I am beginning to work on a project in a Django Web with Visual Studio. As far as I try to create a superuser or try to run it without debugging I get the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
>   "C:\Users\iandrada\Documents\ABRA_WEBSITE\ABRA_WEBSITE\ABRA_WEBSITE\manage.py",
>   line 15, in 
>             from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
>           File "C:\Users\iandrada\Documents\ABRA_WEBSITE\ABRA_WEBSITE\ABRA_WEBSITE\env_ABRA\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py",
>   line 3, in 
>             from django.utils.version import get_version
>           File "C:\Users\iandrada\Documents\ABRA_WEBSITE\ABRA_WEBSITE\ABRA_WEBSITE\env_ABRA\lib\site-packages\django\utils\version.py",
>   line 5, in 
>             import subprocess
>           File "C:\Users\iandrada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 50, in 
>             import signal
>           File "C:\Users\iandrada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\signal.py",
>   line 3, in 
>             from functools import wraps as _wraps
>           File "C:\Users\iandrada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\functools.py",
>   line 23, in 
>             from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
>           File "C:\Users\iandrada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\weakref.py",
>   line 12, in 
>             from _weakref import (      ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref' Compilación del proyecto "ABRA_WEBSITE.pyproj"
>   terminada -- ERROR.

I have tried reinstalling VS, or updating Python to a more recent version, but still haven't found any solution.

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error: There was a problem with the virtual environment setup, so I decided to re-create the virtual environment by executing the command:

```
virtualenv -–system-site-packages C:/FULL/PATH/TO/VIRTUALENV/FOLDER
```